# ffmpeg pipe webcam to output h264

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to pipe the output of `ffmpeg` from the webcam to stdout.

I need this to work on both OS X and Linux,

Right now I have this command:

`ffmpeg -f avfoundation -framerate 30 -i "0" -target pal-vcd ./test.mpg`

But this is not h264 I think and it is writing to a file, which I don't want.

Thank you